# node.js module export return and use object

Tags: javascript, node.js

say i have the following `modelConfiguration.js` file:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database.config');
module.exports = function () {

    const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.database, dbConfig.user, dbConfig.password, {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql',

        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        },

        // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
        operatorsAliases: false
    });


    const employee = sequelize.define('employee', {
        id:{
            type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        token: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT
    });

    return sequelize;


};
```

Now here as you  can see i return the `sequelize` object.

Now i wish to set a variable equal to the object returned so in my `server.js` i do the following:

```
const seq = require('./models/modelConfig');
```

However this does not work.

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong? (Maybe ive misunderstood something)

Comment: Your `module.exports` returns a function that when _called_ returns that `Sequelize` instance.

Comment: `const seq = require('./models/modelConfig')();` This is what you should do.

Comment: Yup, get rid of the function and just return sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `require('./models/modelConfig');` returns a function that initializes Sequelize.

You should call the method to get an instance:

```
const seqInitializer = require('./models/modelConfig');
const seq = seqInitializer();
```

Alternatively. Just return sequelize directly:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database.config');
function initSequelize() {

    const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.database, dbConfig.user, dbConfig.password, {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql',

        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        },

        // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
        operatorsAliases: false
    });


    const employee = sequelize.define('employee', {
        id:{
            type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        token: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT
    });

    return sequelize;


};
module.exports = initSequelize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Try to add this.. It will give u back an object instead of function

```
const seq = require('./models/modelConfig')();
```